# Using namespace to isolate hierarchy of classes

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a fairly large hierarchy of classes derived from a base class `Entity`. I would like to group these classes into a separate namespace. Currently, this looks like the following:

```
namespace Entity {
    class Entity {
        //...
    };

    class A : public Entity {  // Instead of AEntity from before.
        //...
    };

    class B : public Entity {  // Instead of BEntity from before.
        //...
    };
}

int main() {
    // Example usage:
    Entity::Entity *entity = new Entity::B();
    delete entity;
}
```

Having to write `Entity::Entity` is a bit unfortunate, so I'm wondering if this is a good idea? Adding `using namespace Entity` or `typedef Entity::Entity Entity` in the global namespace doesn't work (as that would conflict with `namespace Entity`). They could be added within `main` though...

Should I avoid naming the namespace the same as the base class within it? Or is this common practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I avoid naming the namespace the same as the base class within it?

I would. As well as the conflict you point out, it makes it awkward to refer to the namespace from within itself (sometimes necessary when names at namespace scope are hidden within a nested scope). Neither issue is particularly serious, but why make life harder than necessary?

You might call the namespace `Entities`, since it contains multiple entity types; and/or perhaps call the base class `Base`, since the namespace completes the description of what it's the base of.

I tend to used different naming conventions for namespaces (`lower_case`) and classes (`Capitalised`), but that might not suit your aesthetics or arbitrary corporate dictats.

Comment: Our naming convention dictates that namespaces and types should use PascalCase, but using the plural form is a great idea, thanks!